# Usando el singular/plural para adjetivos en la formula: "uno de los"

Tags: gramática, adjetivos, plurales

¿Cómo es correcto?

> Uno de los órganos tubulares más fascinante y hermoso en el Ecuador es el de la Iglesia de la Compañía de Jesús de Quito.

o

> Uno de los órganos tubulares más **fascinantes** y **hermosos** en el Ecuador es el de la Iglesia de la Compañía de Jesús de Quito.

En Rumano, se usaría el plural, pero en español no estoy seguro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es correcto en plural, puesto que `fascinantes y hermosos` se refiere a `los órganos tubulares`. Sería más o menos equivalente a:

> Hablemos de **los órganos tubulares más fascinantes y hermosos en el
>   Ecuador**. Uno de **ellos** es el de la Iglesia de la Compañía de Jesús de
>   Quito.

Comment: Bien clarita la respuesta, y aprovecho para darte la bienvenida al sitio, Only.